# how to call aspx page from offline html with using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have html page which is located on hard disk (in the browser: file:///C:/index.html). I want to load some data from aspx page when I open this html page.
Aspx page is deployed on the webserver (e.g. http://servername/json.aspx) and returns json data:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/json";
Response.Write(jsonString);
```

I have tried a lot of combinations of jquery calls but not sucesfully.

Basically I want to achieve something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function()    
{
    $("#myButt").click(function()
    {           
        $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "http://servername/json.aspx",
           data: "id=1",
           success: function(msg){
             alert(msg);
            },           
        });                             
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Can somebody help me how to achieve this?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're going to run afoul of the cross-domain policy with this.  There are some potential hacks: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/ if you must go down that path, but it's better (imo) to use a proxy of some kind or find another solution.